# How to color specific rows in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have a ag grid and I want to color some row numbers only. For example, after processing I find out that I have to color row # 1, 4 & 5 ONLY.

I tried getRowStyle function of ag-grid but in vain

```
gridOptions.getRowStyle = function(params) {
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
    return { background: 'red' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/. It seems like you have taken the code from there, so it should work. And remember, using the function you posted only work on odd rows (not on row number 4). If you need 1, 4 & 5 only, then you should match those indices.

Comment: Also. If you can describe exactly what's not working, it will be easier to help.

Comment: why dont you add function as there is no fix rowindexes and you decide indexes based on procssing of some rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some code [directly from the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/)

If you need to color only some rows. You need to know which rows to color. I am assuming that you have a state for this. Maybe a variable called `indices`?

```
indices: Array<number> = [1,4,5]; // color these rows

gridOptions.getRowStyle = (params) => { // should use params, not indices in the first braces. Binds the component to this. Can use indices in the function now
    if (this.indices.includes(params.node.rowIndex)) {
        return { background: 'red' }
    }
}
```

You need to be more specific if you need more help. I don't know what is not working.

[Here is a Plunkr with an example](https://plnkr.co/edit/VA9Lnq9OD0dp0NzCGxcL?p=preview). I am not sure how you have set everything up in your project, but you can probably get some ideas on how to modify your code to fit with the example I adjusted from the ag-grid docs. I hope the example help

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at it and it didn't help. I need specific solution of coloring only few rows like 1, 3, 6. If you can help.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution but it seems the array indices is not readable inside the function(). I tried your solution and it gives me this error: Can not read property indices of undefined at getRowStyle

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. I see now that `this` is pointing to the gridOptions instead of your class. I have updated my answer, by changing the way the function is called, binding your component to this, instead of gridOptions.

Comment: I still have Cannot read property 'indices' of undefined error. Please see the plunkr code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/OT6dJlqbhn0K87CNxrmk?p=preview

Comment: I made a mistake. The `getRowStyles = (indices) => {}` should actually be `getRowStyles = (params) => {}`. I updated my answer, and added a plunkr

Comment: @KashIf Here is an update for you, a modified example with the plunkr you provided: https://plnkr.co/edit/AuKAUS?p=preview

Comment: for some reason the code works on plunkr but on in my actual project :(
getRowClassRules = (indices) => {
    return {
      "sick-days-warning": function(params) {
        return indices.includes(params.node.rowIndex);
      },
      "sick-days-breach": "data.sickDays > 8"
    }
  }

Comment: You either have to update your question with more relevant code, change your project to fit with the modified plunkr you provided, or create a new plunkr with your current project code. I cannot help you more than I already have without more information.

Comment: I have difficulty in accessing the value  of indices inside ag grid functions. You have given the example for getRowClassRules and I'm trying to do it for getRowStyleScheduled exactly the same way but getting the error.

Comment: Did you have a lookmat the Plunkr I added to the answer? https://plnkr.co/edit/VA9Lnq9OD0dp0NzCGxcL?p=preview It has an example using styles instead of class.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it. I appreciate your effort and time. This took around 3 weeks of my life.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this , as you want to highlight rows based on your processing of rows, so should put some rules as below and highlight rows

```
gridOptions.rowClassRules: {
  // apply green to 2008
  'rag-green-outer': function(params) { return params.data.year === 2008},

  // apply amber 2004
  'rag-amber-outer': function(params) { return params.data.year === 2004},

  // apply red to 2000
  'rag-red-outer': function(params) { return params.data.year === 2000}
}
```

by this way you can color your row based on your criteria. This taken from ag gird webporal only.